# Modificar el DOM de un DataTable

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, datatables, dom

Tengo una tabla donde tengo todos los registros de una tabla de `sql`.

Y debajo de cada columna tengo un `input` de tipo `text` que el plugin de `DataTable` me lo implementa ya para filtrar datos. Sería algo como esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que yo quiero es que cuando le de click en un `div` en ese campo de texto se ponga como valor tal palabra a designar... el problema viene cuando quiero acceder al `DOM` de ese input, como yo no lo genero no me deja... he intentado con este código.

```
var div = document.getElementById("lblAtenciones");
var input = document.getElementById("EstatusId");

div.addEventListener("click", function () {
   input.value = "En Atención";
});
```

Pero me dice un error en consola que dice:

> caught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value')
> at HTMLDivElement.

Esta es mi tabla

```
<table id="solicitudesAdmin" class="display wrap" style="width:100%;">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Acciones</th>
                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SolicitudId)</th>
                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nombre)</th>
                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contacto.Sucursal.Cliente.Nombre)</th>
                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contacto.Nombre)</th>
                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ServicioNivel.Descripcion)</th>
                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ServicioSubCategoria.Descripcion)</th>
                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SolicitudCanalAtencion.Nombre)</th>
                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SolicitudEstatus.Nombre)</th>
                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SolicitudPrioridad.Nombre)</th>
                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SolicitudTipo.Nombre)</th>
                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Fecha)</th>
                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FechaVencimiento)</th>
                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TotalHorasInvertidas)</th>
                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PorcentajeAvance)</th>
                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Agente.Nombre)</th>
                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FechaCierre)</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var item in Model)
                            {
                                var model = Model.ToList();
                                {
                                    var index = model.IndexOf(item);
                                }
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div style="margin: 0px 2px 0px 0px ">
                                                @Html.Raw(@Html.ActionLink("Editar", "Edit", new { id = @item.SolicitudId }, new { @class = "btn btn-info" }).ToHtmlString().Replace("Editar", "<i class=\"fas fa-pencil-alt\"></i>"))
                                            </div>
                                            @if (User.IsInRole("Administrador") || User.IsInRole("Agente"))
                                            {
                                                if (item.Agente != null)
                                                {
                                                    if (item.Agente.Correo != "indefinido@indefinido.com")
                                                    {
                                                        <div style="margin: 0px 2px 0px 0px ">
                                                            @Html.Raw(@Html.ActionLink("Editar", "Create", "SolicitudAtenciones", new { id = @item.SolicitudId }, new { @class = "btn btn-info" }).ToHtmlString().Replace("Editar", "<i class=\"fas fa-tasks\"></i>"))
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div style="margin: 0px 2px 0px 0px ">
                                                            @*@Html.Raw(@Html.ActionLink("Editar", "Create", "SolicitudSeguimientos", new { id = @item.SolicitudId }, new { @class = "btn btn-info" }).ToHtmlString().Replace("Editar", "<i class=\"fa fa-comments\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i>"))*@
                                                            @if (@item.SeguimientosNoLeidos > 0)
                                                            {
                                                                <button id="botonSeguimiento-@item.SolicitudId"
                                                                        type="button"
                                                                        class="btn btn-info"
                                                                        data-id="@item.SolicitudId"
                                                                        data-toggle="modal"
                                                                        data-target="#Seguimiento"
                                                                        data-titulo="@item.Nombre"
                                                                        @*style="padding-left: 6px; padding-right: 0px;"*@>

                                                                    @*ANIMACION DEL ICONO SIN COLOR DENTRO DEL BOTON*@
                                                                    @*<i class="fa fa-comments blink" style="animation-duration: 2s"></i>*@

                                                                    @*ANIMACION DEL ICONO CON COLOR DENTRO DEL BOTON*@
                                                                    @*<i class="fa fa-comments blink_me" style="color: #00e600;" }"></i>*@

                                                                    @*BADGE DE NUEVO MENSAJE CON CONTEO DE NUEVOS MENSAJES*@
                                                                    @*<span style="font-weight: bold;" class="badge badge-warning navbar-badge">@item.SeguimientosNoLeidos</span>*@

                                                                    @*BADGE DE NUEVO MENSAJE SIN CONTEO DE NUEVOS MENSAJES Y ANIMACIÓN*@
                                                                    <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
                                                                    <span style="font-size:xx-small; animation-duration: 2s" class="blink position-absolute top-0 start-100 translate-middle p-1 bg-red border border-light rounded-circle">
                                                                        <span class="visually-hidden"></span>
                                                                    </span>

                                                                    @*BADGE DE NUEVO MENSAJE CON CONTEO DE NUEVOS MENSAJES Y SIN ANIMACIÓN*@
                                                                    @*<span class="badge badge-success navbar-badge">@item.SeguimientosNoLeidos</span>*@
                                                                </button>
                                                            }
                                                            else
                                                            {
                                                                <button type="button"
                                                                        class="btn btn-info"
                                                                        data-id="@item.SolicitudId"
                                                                        data-toggle="modal"
                                                                        data-target="#Seguimiento"
                                                                        data-titulo="@item.Nombre">
                                                                    <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
                                                                </button>
                                                            }
                                                        </div>
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                            <div style="margin: 0px 2px 0px 0px ">
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" data-delete-id="index" onclick="jsEliminar2(@item.SolicitudId);"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @item.SolicitudId
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @item.Nombre
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @item.Contacto.Sucursal.Cliente.Nombre
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @item.Contacto.Nombre
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @item.ServicioNivel.Descripcion
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @item.ServicioSubCategoria.Descripcion
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @item.SolicitudCanalAtencion.Nombre
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @item.SolicitudEstatus.Nombre
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @item.SolicitudPrioridad.Nombre
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @item.SolicitudTipo.Nombre
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @*@String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", @item.Fecha)*@
                                        @item.Fecha
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @item.FechaVencimiento
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @item.TotalHorasInvertidas
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @item.PorcentajeAvance
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @if (item.Agente != null)
                                        {
                                            @item.Agente.Nombre;
                                        }
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @*@String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", @item.FechaCierre)*@
                                        @item.FechaCierre
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Acciones</th>
                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SolicitudId)</th>
                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nombre)</th>
                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contacto.Sucursal.Cliente.Nombre)</th>
                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contacto.Nombre)</th>
                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ServicioNivel.Descripcion)</th>
                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ServicioSubCategoria.Descripcion)</th>
                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SolicitudCanalAtencion.Nombre)</th>
                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SolicitudEstatus.Nombre)</th>
                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SolicitudPrioridad.Nombre)</th>
                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SolicitudTipo.Nombre)</th>
                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Fecha)</th>
                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FechaVencimiento)</th>
                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TotalHorasInvertidas)</th>
                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PorcentajeAvance)</th>
                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Agente.Nombre)</th>
                                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FechaCierre)</th>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
```

Y para darle formato a la tabla con el `DataTable`.

```
var tableAdmin = $("#solicitudesAdmin").DataTable({
                //var tableAdmin = $('#solicitudesAdmin').removeAttr('width').DataTable({
                //scrollY: "300px",
                scrollX: true,
                //sScrollXInner: "100%",
                scrollCollapse: true,
                //columnDefs: [
                //    {
                //        width: 200,
                //        targets: 0,
                //    }],
                paging: true,
                ////lengthChange: true,
                searching: true,
                ordering: true,
                //info: true,
                //autoWidth: true,
                responsive: true,
                colReorder: true,
                orderCellsTop: true,
                ////fixedHeader: false,
                //columnDefs: [{ width: '50%', targets: 3 }],
                //fixedColumns: true,
                dom: 'lBfrtip',
                stateSave: true,
                stateDuration: 0,
                columnDefs: [
                    { width: "5%", targets: 0 }
                    //,
                    //{ type: 'date', targets: 10 },
                    //{ type: 'date', targets: 14 }
                ],
                //fixedColumns: {
                //    left: 1
                //},
                autoWidth: false,
                //fixedColumns: true,

                order: [[0, 'desc']],

                lengthMenu: [
                      [10, 25, 50, 100, -1],
                      ['10', '25', '50', '100', 'Todo']
                ],
                buttons: [
                      {
                          extend: 'colvis',
                          text: '<i class="fa fa-toggle-on"></i> Columnas',
                          //className: 'btn btn-secondary btn-sm'
                      },
                      {
                          extend: 'excelHtml5',
                          filename: 'solicitudesAdmin',
                          title: 'solicitudesAdmin',
                          text: 'Exportar a Excel',
                          exportOptions: {
                              columns: ':visible',
                          }
                      },
                      {
                          text: 'Borrar Filtros',
                          action: function (e, dt, node, config) {

                              var coleccion = $("#solicitudesAdmin thead input");

                              console.log('Coleccion: ' + coleccion.length);
                              console.log('borrando con coleccion');
                              for (i = 0; i < coleccion.length - 1 ; i++) {
                                  console.log(i);
                                  elem = coleccion[i];
                                  //elem.value = '';
                                  if (elem != null) {
                                      console.log(elem.id);
                                      document.getElementById(elem.id).value = '';
                                      //console.log(i + ' es: ' + elem.value);
                                  }

                              }

                              console.log('borrando');
                              var table = $('#solicitudesAdmin').DataTable();
                              table
                               .search('')
                               .columns().search('')
                               .draw();
                          }
                      }
                ],
                language: {
                    url: '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.25/i18n/Spanish.json'
                }
            });
```

Comment: agrega tu HTML quizás así se esclarezca tu problema especifico

Comment: Luis, la idea de StackOverflow es que tanto preguntas como respuestas tengan el contenido relevante. Por lo mismo, no dejes el código relacionado a la pregunta en un link, que mañana podría estar roto. Prepara un [mcve] y deja el código relevante como parte de la misma pregunta. Para más información lee [ask]. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me cree una variable para obtener el `input` de búsqueda del plugin del `DataTable`.

```
var searchBoxEstatus = $('#solicitudesAdmin input[id="EstatusId"]');
            console.log('input -> ', searchBoxEstatus);
            $('#lblAtenciones').on('click', function () {
                //searchBoxEstatus.focus();
                searchBoxEstatus.val('En Atención');
                //searchBoxEstatus.trigger('input');
                var e = $.Event("keyup", { keyCode: 13 });
                console.log('tecla -> ', e);
                searchBoxEstatus.trigger(e);
            });
```

No me funcionaba así nada más así que le tuve que añadir un `Event`, que cuando se terminara de poner el texto en el `input`, se simulara que se clickera la tecla enter.